# Is XSLT disappearing in .NET

Tags: .net, xslt, xpath

I'm looking into courses on XSLT but I have read XSLT and xpath is fading in .NET. Reading this [link](http://www.ektron.co.uk/billcavablog/the-slow-quiet-disappearance-of-xslt-in-net/) it seems that I should invest my learning elsewhere. What other tools in .net can I use to transform xml and is it true that XSLT is disappearing?

Comment: I would suggest that this is a subjective question that's not really suited for this site (perhaps the question about "what other tools" is valid, but as written it's not specific enough to be answered).  XSLT isn't "disappearing", but perhaps there are other features in .NET that make XSLT a more complicated and expensive choice of technology in most scenarios.  Either way, you should be asking yourself *why* you want to do a course on XSLT: do you have a specific reason, a project to complete, or are you just learning for learning's sake?

Comment: You might be right: I think more and more of the kind of people who see the benefits of XSLT are choosing to run on a Java platform rather than .NET. So perhaps it's time you took your career in the Java direction. But all information on trends, including this comment, is entirely anecdotal and unscientific.

Comment: Why would you ask such a question? .NET provides full support for XSLT 1.0: the fastest XSLT 1.0 processor (XslCompiledTransform), a good IDE as part of Visual Studio (the XML editor and the XSLT Debugger) and even a tool to create an XSLT executable file (dll) for faster, repeated executions. And all of these is in the latest version of .NET and Visual Studio.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I asked the question because I didn't know the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old classes will still be *there*, but it doesn't look like a direction for significant development effort at this time. So you should be able to use 1.0 at least - which frankly works well enough for most common operations.

Alternatives:

- (use the current xslt 1.0 tools in .NET)
- alternative 3rd party xslt tools (or saxon if you prefer)
- loading into a DOM such as `XDocument` / `XmlDocument` and manipulating that (which still provides xpath support etc)
- deserializing the xml into an object model and manipulating the model; perhaps re-serializing
- deserializing into an object model and using a templating language such as T4 or razor

Personally, I like xslt - it is powerful and elegant for a few scenarios; it is at least worth knowing about, but... I wouldn't spend ages on courses unless I know I had a very specific purpose in mind.

Comment: Sharepoint 2010 is a perfect example of how **NOT** to use XSLT :)

Answer (score -1):

Sharepoint 2010 uses XSLT extensively. I wish they will kill it off. Extremely poor development environment :(